# Install4j autoupdate version comparision

Tags: install4j

Can you please say how version compare works for UpdateCheck? How Checker determines that version in `updates.xml` is newer than his version?
For example, my versioning is using formula `YEAR/MAJOR.MINOR`: `2015/1`, `2015/1.1`, `2015/1.2`, `2015/2`, `2016/1` and so on. But I also have specific releases as `2015/1.2-LOK15`. How these version numbers will be compared during version check?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install4j transforms the version string into an array of version components. The separators for creating numeric version components are ".", "-" and "_". Each version component has an optional leading text part and a trailing numeric part. The text parts are compared lexically, the version parts are compared numerically.

Version components that start with non-numeric characters, like "LOK15" are generally considered to be pre-cursor versions to the same version component without the text part (like "beta" or "RC"). So `2015/1.2-LOK15` is considered to be lower than `2015/1.2`. However `2015/1.2-15LOK` would be higher than `2015/1.2`.

Comment: And what about `2015/1`, `2015/1.1`, `2015/1.2`, `2015/2`, `2016/1`? How 0are they compared? What is comparation algorithm?

Comment: It would be great if it is possible to choose comparison algorithm in install4j.

Comment: I've edited the answer. I've added a feature request for a custom version comparison algorithm.